# Multiple column filter in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am able to filter data in datagrid based on one column at a time. I want to filter data in datagrid based on two or more columns at a time.
currently i am using

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "[Branch]='" + comboBox3.Text.ToString()+ "'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is understanding the syntax to build the string for `Filter`. You can simply add more properties to the `Filter` string like this:

```
//for 3 columns
bs.Filter = "[Column1] = 'Value1' AND [Column2] = 'Value2' AND [Column3] = 'Value3'";
```

More info about possible stuff you can use to build a `Filter` string can be found here [string expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot @King King.My bad...it was so simple